# How to get text from textview?

Tags: android, textview, gettext

I'm trying to get a text from a `TextView` so I tried to use `getText()` method but didn't work. I'm using `fragments` only, so there's a way I can get my text from the `TextView`?

Ps. I tried with `getEditText()` but I get `NULL`.

Comment: using `getText()` from `TextView` is a correct way, so can you provide your whole fragment? It will help us a lot to find out the solution

Answer (score 2):

you are probably calling `TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourInFragmentTextView);` on your activity layout?

You need to get the reference to the actual view in the fragment.

First you need a reference to the inflated fragment and than call

```
TextView textView = (TextView) myFragment.findViewById(R.id.yourInFragmentTextView);
String text = textView.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

`String str = textview.getText().toString();` should work
try clearing cache and restart